# Ошибка (Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'G_CODE.table1' in 'field list')

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Буду признателен помощи.

**2 таблицы:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Задача:** получить все товары с штрих-кодами с началом действия в 2010 году.

**Мой код:**

```
SELECT G_CODE.table1, F_NAME.table1, EAN.table2
FROM table1, table2
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON G_CODE.table1 = G_CODE.t2
WHERE year(DATE_BEGIN.t2) = 2010;
```

Получаю ошибку:"Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'G_CODE.table1' in 'field list'
"

Не пойму где надо исправить, ведь данное поле(G_CODE.table1) есть.

Comment: Ну у поля имя ведь явно не `G_CODE.table1` верно? Вот Вам и пишет `Unknown column` -- неизвестная колонка. Синтаксис должен быть вида `table.column`, а не наоборот.

Comment: `G_CODE.table1` означает, что вы обращаетесь к полю `table1` в таблице `G_CODE`.  Поменяйте в своём запросе название таблицы и поля местами: `SELECT table1.G_CODE ...` и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Операция "запятая", являясь аналогом CROSS JOIN, имеет более низкий приоритет, чем явные JOIN. Соответственно, если расставить скобки с учётом приоритетов, запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT G_CODE.table1, F_NAME.table1, EAN.table2
FROM table1, 
     ( table2
       JOIN table2 AS t2 ON G_CODE.table1 = G_CODE.t2 
       )
WHERE year(DATE_BEGIN.t2) = 2010;
```

Очевидно, что внутри скобок никакие ссылки на внешнюю для выражения в скобках таблицу table1 - не видны.

---

Это даже без учёта путаницы имён объектов (правильно - `таблица.поле`, но никак не `поле.таблица`), что хорошо описано в комментариях к вопросу.

Comment: Подозреваю, что автор вопроса просто не знает, что если таблица уже есть в `JOIN`, то её не нужно перечислять в `FROM`, чтобы иметь доступ к её полям.